# ¿Como determinar los subniveles de un array? Usando una funcion recursiva

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursión

Tengo un tabla en la base de datos en el cual guardo todas las funciones de mi menú, esta tiene las siguientes columnas:

> tabla: funciones / 
> columnas: id, id_padre, icono, link, titulo

Y yo quiero ordenar los padres e hijos según los tengo registrado en la `db`, esto lo quiero hacer con una [función recursiva](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Que-es-la-recursividad-o-recursion-Un-ejemplo-con-JavaScript.aspx).

El problema recae en que no se en que nivel de subparte voy, ejemplo, cuando va por un 3er submenu. Solo recorro cada uno de los items de manera ordenada pero aun no se determinar esa parte (niveles del menu).

Aca lo que llevo de la función:

```js
var todoMenus;

function GenerarMenus(codigoMenu, esSub) {
  if(esSub){
    console.log('OPCION P');
  }else{
   if(codigoMenu == 0){
     console.log('OPCIONES PRINCIPALES');
    }else{
     console.log('OPCION SUB');
    }
  }

  var menuGenerado = '';
  
  var menus = [];
  $.each(todoMenus, function (i, v) {
    if (v.id_padre == codigoMenu) {
      menus.push(v);
    }
  });
  
  if (menus.length != 0) {
   console.log(menus);
  }

  if (menus != undefined) {
    $.each(menus, function (i, v) {
      console.log(v.titulo);
      
      if(v.id_padre == 0){
       var esSub = true;
      }else{
       var esSub = false;
      }
   
      var subMenu = GenerarMenus(v.id, esSub);
      if (subMenu.length == 0) {
      
      } else {
      
      }
    });
  }
  return menuGenerado;
}


var menujson = {
  "menu": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-dashboard fa-fw",
    "link": "/",
    "titulo": "Tablero"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-tasks fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Procesos"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "id_padre": 2,
    "icono": "fa fa-list-ol fa-fw",
    "link": "/lotes",
    "titulo": "Lotes"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "id_padre": 2,
    "icono": "fa fa-eraser fa-fw",
    "link": "/limpieza",
    "titulo": "Limpieza"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "id_padre": 2,
    "icono": "fa fa-stop fa-fw",
    "link": "/paradasopera",
    "titulo": "Paradas"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "id_padre": 2,
    "icono": "fa fa-wrench fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Mantenimiento"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "id_padre": 6,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/planes",
    "titulo": "Planes"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "id_padre": 6,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/calendario",
    "titulo": "Calendario"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-file-text-o fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Reportes"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "id_padre": 9,
    "icono": "fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw",
    "link": "/estadisticos",
    "titulo": "Estadisticos"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "id_padre": 9,
    "icono": "fa fa-building-o fa-fw",
    "link": "/estaticos",
    "titulo": "Estaticos"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "id_padre": 9,
    "icono": "fa fa-file fa-fw",
    "link": "/parametrizados",
    "titulo": "Parametrizados"
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-wrench fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Opciones"
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-industry fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Marcas de Equipos"
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "id_padre": 22,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/marcas",
    "titulo": "Marcas"
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "id_padre": 22,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/modelos",
    "titulo": "Modelos"
  },
  {
    "id": 32,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-clock-o fa-fw",
    "link": "/turnos",
    "titulo": "Turnos"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-flask fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Productos de Elaboración"
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "id_padre": 14,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/productos",
    "titulo": "Productos"
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "id_padre": 14,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/unidadesdemedicion",
    "titulo": "Unidades de Medición"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-arrows-alt fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Areas y Procesos de Producción"
  },
  {
    "id": 30,
    "id_padre": 15,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/areas",
    "titulo": "Areas"
  },
  {
    "id": 31,
    "id_padre": 15,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/procesos",
    "titulo": "Procesos "
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-steam fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Registro de Equipos"
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "id_padre": 16,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/equipos",
    "titulo": "Equipos"
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "id_padre": 16,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/partes",
    "titulo": "Partes"
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "id_padre": 16,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/subpartes",
    "titulo": "Subpartes"
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-user fa-fw",
    "link": "/personas",
    "titulo": "Personas"
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-gears fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Configuración"
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "id_padre": 18,
    "icono": "fa fa-users fa-fw",
    "link": "/usuarios",
    "titulo": "Usuarios"
  },
  {
    "id": 20,
    "id_padre": 18,
    "icono": "fa fa-suitcase fa-fw",
    "link": "/perfiles",
    "titulo": "Perfiles"
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "id_padre": 18,
    "icono": "fa fa-database fa-fw",
    "link": "/respaldo",
    "titulo": "Respaldo"
  }
  ]
};


$( document ).ready(function() {
  todoMenus = menujson.menu;
  var menuGenerado = GenerarMenus(0, false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**NOTA:** los resultados no se imprimen completos en la consola de fiddler de esSO, se visualizan completos en la del navegador.

Comment: Un problema muy grande que veo es el diseño de tu arreglo, yo imaginaba más bien que cada elemento que tuviera un padre estaría dentro de ese elemento padre como un elemento(arreglo de arreglos), haciendo así tu arreglo de múltiples niveles, hay forma de que este arreglo se pueda cambiar de esta manera?

Comment: @Lixus no entendi muy bien :-/

Comment: Por ejemplo `{"id" : 2, "id_padre" : 0, ...., "hijos": {"id": 17, "id_padre": 2}, {"id": 19: "id_padre": 2,..., "hijos": {},{} } }` De tal forma que cada registro tenga un atributo `hijos` donde se almacenan los submenus, y los hijos pueden tener hijos y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Así como lo veo se me ocurre que por cada elemento del arreglo, hagas un nuevo recorrido buscando todo elemento cuyo id_padre sea igual al id del elemento actual de tu primer iteración, y así sucesivamente hasta terminar el arreglo.

Comment: @Lixus No puedo hacerlo así, por que los id de cada elemento debo relacionarlos a otra tabla. Si lo que entiendo, es que cada elemento tenga sus hijos, entonces no puedo relacionar los hijos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El *arrays* que muestras es plano por lo que no puedes determinar *sub niveles*, en todo caso el "**id_padre**" te indica el *sub nivel*.

Por lo antes expuesto debo entender que quieres ordenar el *arrays* en *sub niveles* dados por la relación *padre/hijos*, de ser esto correcto aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo:

```js
var menujson = {
  "menu": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-dashboard fa-fw",
    "link": "/",
    "titulo": "Tablero"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-tasks fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Procesos"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "id_padre": 2,
    "icono": "fa fa-list-ol fa-fw",
    "link": "/lotes",
    "titulo": "Lotes"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "id_padre": 2,
    "icono": "fa fa-eraser fa-fw",
    "link": "/limpieza",
    "titulo": "Limpieza"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "id_padre": 2,
    "icono": "fa fa-stop fa-fw",
    "link": "/paradasopera",
    "titulo": "Paradas"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "id_padre": 2,
    "icono": "fa fa-wrench fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Mantenimiento"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "id_padre": 6,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/planes",
    "titulo": "Planes"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "id_padre": 6,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/calendario",
    "titulo": "Calendario"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-file-text-o fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Reportes"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "id_padre": 9,
    "icono": "fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw",
    "link": "/estadisticos",
    "titulo": "Estadisticos"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "id_padre": 9,
    "icono": "fa fa-building-o fa-fw",
    "link": "/estaticos",
    "titulo": "Estaticos"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "id_padre": 9,
    "icono": "fa fa-file fa-fw",
    "link": "/parametrizados",
    "titulo": "Parametrizados"
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-wrench fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Opciones"
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-industry fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Marcas de Equipos"
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "id_padre": 22,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/marcas",
    "titulo": "Marcas"
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "id_padre": 22,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/modelos",
    "titulo": "Modelos"
  },
  {
    "id": 32,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-clock-o fa-fw",
    "link": "/turnos",
    "titulo": "Turnos"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-flask fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Productos de Elaboración"
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "id_padre": 14,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/productos",
    "titulo": "Productos"
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "id_padre": 14,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/unidadesdemedicion",
    "titulo": "Unidades de Medición"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-arrows-alt fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Areas y Procesos de Producción"
  },
  {
    "id": 30,
    "id_padre": 15,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/areas",
    "titulo": "Areas"
  },
  {
    "id": 31,
    "id_padre": 15,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/procesos",
    "titulo": "Procesos "
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-steam fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Registro de Equipos"
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "id_padre": 16,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/equipos",
    "titulo": "Equipos"
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "id_padre": 16,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/partes",
    "titulo": "Partes"
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "id_padre": 16,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/subpartes",
    "titulo": "Subpartes"
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-user fa-fw",
    "link": "/personas",
    "titulo": "Personas"
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-gears fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Configuración"
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "id_padre": 18,
    "icono": "fa fa-users fa-fw",
    "link": "/usuarios",
    "titulo": "Usuarios"
  },
  {
    "id": 20,
    "id_padre": 18,
    "icono": "fa fa-suitcase fa-fw",
    "link": "/perfiles",
    "titulo": "Perfiles"
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "id_padre": 18,
    "icono": "fa fa-database fa-fw",
    "link": "/respaldo",
    "titulo": "Respaldo"
  }
  ]
};

function ordenar(j) {
 menu = { menu: [] };

 for (n in j.menu) {
  insertar(j.menu[n], 0, menu.menu);
 }
 return menu;
}

function insertar(j, l, menu) {
 for (n in menu) {
  if (menu[n].id == j.id_padre) {
   if (menu[n].menu == undefined)
    menu[n].menu = [];
   return menu[n].menu.push(j);
  } else {
   if (menu[n].menu)
    if (insertar(j, l+1, menu[n].menu))
     return true;
  }
 }
 if (l)
  return false;

 menu.push(j);
}

menu = ordenar(menujson);
console.log(menu);
```

Una vez ordenado te sera fácil saber el *sub nivel* donde te encuentras:

```js
menu = {
  "menu": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "id_padre": 0,
      "icono": "fa fa-dashboard fa-fw",
      "link": "/",
      "titulo": "Tablero"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "id_padre": 0,
      "icono": "fa fa-tasks fa-fw",
      "link": "#",
      "titulo": "Procesos",
      "menu": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "id_padre": 2,
          "icono": "fa fa-list-ol fa-fw",
          "link": "/lotes",
          "titulo": "Lotes"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "id_padre": 2,
          "icono": "fa fa-eraser fa-fw",
          "link": "/limpieza",
          "titulo": "Limpieza"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "id_padre": 2,
          "icono": "fa fa-stop fa-fw",
          "link": "/paradasopera",
          "titulo": "Paradas"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "id_padre": 2,
          "icono": "fa fa-wrench fa-fw",
          "link": "#",
          "titulo": "Mantenimiento",
          "menu": [
            {
              "id": 7,
              "id_padre": 6,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/planes",
              "titulo": "Planes"
            },
            {
              "id": 8,
              "id_padre": 6,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/calendario",
              "titulo": "Calendario"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "id_padre": 0,
      "icono": "fa fa-file-text-o fa-fw",
      "link": "#",
      "titulo": "Reportes",
      "menu": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "id_padre": 9,
          "icono": "fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw",
          "link": "/estadisticos",
          "titulo": "Estadisticos"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "id_padre": 9,
          "icono": "fa fa-building-o fa-fw",
          "link": "/estaticos",
          "titulo": "Estaticos"
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "id_padre": 9,
          "icono": "fa fa-file fa-fw",
          "link": "/parametrizados",
          "titulo": "Parametrizados"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "id_padre": 0,
      "icono": "fa fa-wrench fa-fw",
      "link": "#",
      "titulo": "Opciones",
      "menu": [
        {
          "id": 22,
          "id_padre": 13,
          "icono": "fa fa-industry fa-fw",
          "link": "#",
          "titulo": "Marcas de Equipos",
          "menu": [
            {
              "id": 23,
              "id_padre": 22,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/marcas",
              "titulo": "Marcas"
            },
            {
              "id": 24,
              "id_padre": 22,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/modelos",
              "titulo": "Modelos"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 32,
          "id_padre": 13,
          "icono": "fa fa-clock-o fa-fw",
          "link": "/turnos",
          "titulo": "Turnos"
        },
        {
          "id": 14,
          "id_padre": 13,
          "icono": "fa fa-flask fa-fw",
          "link": "#",
          "titulo": "Productos de Elaboración",
          "menu": [
            {
              "id": 25,
              "id_padre": 14,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/productos",
              "titulo": "Productos"
            },
            {
              "id": 26,
              "id_padre": 14,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/unidadesdemedicion",
              "titulo": "Unidades de Medición"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 15,
          "id_padre": 13,
          "icono": "fa fa-arrows-alt fa-fw",
          "link": "#",
          "titulo": "Areas y Procesos de Producción",
          "menu": [
            {
              "id": 30,
              "id_padre": 15,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/areas",
              "titulo": "Areas"
            },
            {
              "id": 31,
              "id_padre": 15,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/procesos",
              "titulo": "Procesos "
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 16,
          "id_padre": 13,
          "icono": "fa fa-steam fa-fw",
          "link": "#",
          "titulo": "Registro de Equipos",
          "menu": [
            {
              "id": 27,
              "id_padre": 16,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/equipos",
              "titulo": "Equipos"
            },
            {
              "id": 28,
              "id_padre": 16,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/partes",
              "titulo": "Partes"
            },
            {
              "id": 29,
              "id_padre": 16,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/subpartes",
              "titulo": "Subpartes"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 17,
          "id_padre": 13,
          "icono": "fa fa-user fa-fw",
          "link": "/personas",
          "titulo": "Personas"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "id_padre": 0,
      "icono": "fa fa-gears fa-fw",
      "link": "#",
      "titulo": "Configuración",
      "menu": [
        {
          "id": 19,
          "id_padre": 18,
          "icono": "fa fa-users fa-fw",
          "link": "/usuarios",
          "titulo": "Usuarios"
        },
        {
          "id": 20,
          "id_padre": 18,
          "icono": "fa fa-suitcase fa-fw",
          "link": "/perfiles",
          "titulo": "Perfiles"
        },
        {
          "id": 21,
          "id_padre": 18,
          "icono": "fa fa-database fa-fw",
          "link": "/respaldo",
          "titulo": "Respaldo"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

html=niveles(menu.menu);
console.log(html);
document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML=html;

function niveles(menu, l) {
 if ( l == undefined)
  l=0;
  
 var sp = " ".repeat(l*2);
 html = sp + "<ul>\n"
 
 for (n in menu) {
  html += sp+" <li>"+menu[n].titulo;
  if (menu[n].menu) {
   html += "\n"+niveles(menu[n].menu, l+1, html)+sp+" ";
  };
  html += "</li>\n";
 }
 html += sp + "</ul>\n"
 return html;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"><div>
```

El siguiente ejemplo te muestra como crear una lista de opciones:

```js
menu = {
  "menu": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "id_padre": 0,
      "icono": "fa fa-dashboard fa-fw",
      "link": "/",
      "titulo": "Tablero"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "id_padre": 0,
      "icono": "fa fa-tasks fa-fw",
      "link": "#",
      "titulo": "Procesos",
      "menu": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "id_padre": 2,
          "icono": "fa fa-list-ol fa-fw",
          "link": "/lotes",
          "titulo": "Lotes"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "id_padre": 2,
          "icono": "fa fa-eraser fa-fw",
          "link": "/limpieza",
          "titulo": "Limpieza"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "id_padre": 2,
          "icono": "fa fa-stop fa-fw",
          "link": "/paradasopera",
          "titulo": "Paradas"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "id_padre": 2,
          "icono": "fa fa-wrench fa-fw",
          "link": "#",
          "titulo": "Mantenimiento",
          "menu": [
            {
              "id": 7,
              "id_padre": 6,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/planes",
              "titulo": "Planes"
            },
            {
              "id": 8,
              "id_padre": 6,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/calendario",
              "titulo": "Calendario"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "id_padre": 0,
      "icono": "fa fa-file-text-o fa-fw",
      "link": "#",
      "titulo": "Reportes",
      "menu": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "id_padre": 9,
          "icono": "fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw",
          "link": "/estadisticos",
          "titulo": "Estadisticos"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "id_padre": 9,
          "icono": "fa fa-building-o fa-fw",
          "link": "/estaticos",
          "titulo": "Estaticos"
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "id_padre": 9,
          "icono": "fa fa-file fa-fw",
          "link": "/parametrizados",
          "titulo": "Parametrizados"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "id_padre": 0,
      "icono": "fa fa-wrench fa-fw",
      "link": "#",
      "titulo": "Opciones",
      "menu": [
        {
          "id": 22,
          "id_padre": 13,
          "icono": "fa fa-industry fa-fw",
          "link": "#",
          "titulo": "Marcas de Equipos",
          "menu": [
            {
              "id": 23,
              "id_padre": 22,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/marcas",
              "titulo": "Marcas"
            },
            {
              "id": 24,
              "id_padre": 22,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/modelos",
              "titulo": "Modelos"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 32,
          "id_padre": 13,
          "icono": "fa fa-clock-o fa-fw",
          "link": "/turnos",
          "titulo": "Turnos"
        },
        {
          "id": 14,
          "id_padre": 13,
          "icono": "fa fa-flask fa-fw",
          "link": "#",
          "titulo": "Productos de Elaboración",
          "menu": [
            {
              "id": 25,
              "id_padre": 14,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/productos",
              "titulo": "Productos"
            },
            {
              "id": 26,
              "id_padre": 14,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/unidadesdemedicion",
              "titulo": "Unidades de Medición"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 15,
          "id_padre": 13,
          "icono": "fa fa-arrows-alt fa-fw",
          "link": "#",
          "titulo": "Areas y Procesos de Producción",
          "menu": [
            {
              "id": 30,
              "id_padre": 15,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/areas",
              "titulo": "Areas"
            },
            {
              "id": 31,
              "id_padre": 15,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/procesos",
              "titulo": "Procesos "
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 16,
          "id_padre": 13,
          "icono": "fa fa-steam fa-fw",
          "link": "#",
          "titulo": "Registro de Equipos",
          "menu": [
            {
              "id": 27,
              "id_padre": 16,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/equipos",
              "titulo": "Equipos"
            },
            {
              "id": 28,
              "id_padre": 16,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/partes",
              "titulo": "Partes"
            },
            {
              "id": 29,
              "id_padre": 16,
              "icono": "fa",
              "link": "/subpartes",
              "titulo": "Subpartes"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 17,
          "id_padre": 13,
          "icono": "fa fa-user fa-fw",
          "link": "/personas",
          "titulo": "Personas"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "id_padre": 0,
      "icono": "fa fa-gears fa-fw",
      "link": "#",
      "titulo": "Configuración",
      "menu": [
        {
          "id": 19,
          "id_padre": 18,
          "icono": "fa fa-users fa-fw",
          "link": "/usuarios",
          "titulo": "Usuarios"
        },
        {
          "id": 20,
          "id_padre": 18,
          "icono": "fa fa-suitcase fa-fw",
          "link": "/perfiles",
          "titulo": "Perfiles"
        },
        {
          "id": 21,
          "id_padre": 18,
          "icono": "fa fa-database fa-fw",
          "link": "/respaldo",
          "titulo": "Respaldo"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

html=select1(menu.menu);
console.log(html);
document.getElementById("select1").innerHTML=html;

html=select2(menu.menu);
console.log(html);
document.getElementById("select2").innerHTML=html;

function select1(menu, l, pf) {
 if ( l == undefined)
  l=0, html="", pf="";
 
 for (n in menu) {
  html += "<option>"+pf+menu[n].titulo+"</option>\n";
  if (menu[n].menu) {
   select1(menu[n].menu, l+1, pf+menu[n].titulo+"/");
  };
 };

return html;
}
function select2(menu, l) {
 if ( l == undefined)
  l=0, html="", pf="";

 var sp="&nbsp;".repeat(l*6);
 var n1="";
 
 for (n in menu) {
  if (menu[n].menu || (n1 && menu[n1].menu)) {
   html += "<optgroup></optgroup>\n"
  };
  n1=n;
  html += "<option>"+sp+menu[n].titulo+"</option>\n";
  if (menu[n].menu) {
   select2(menu[n].menu, l+1);
  };
 };

return html;
}
```

```html
<select id="select1"></select>
<select id="select2"></select>
```

Todos estos ejemplos te ilustran de como trabajar con recursividad.

Espero esto te ayude, Saludos!!... ;))

Comment: Buen código, excelente manera de ordenarlo, pero no es lo que quiero, solo que me imprima en consola el nivel que tiene cada opción. Ejemplo, `Procesos es nivel 1`; `Lotes, Limpiezas, Paradas y Mantenimientos son del nivel 2`; `Planes y Calendario son del nivel 3`.

Comment: Te he dejado un segundo ejemplo que muestra como recorrer el arrays y crear un **menu** con niveles, en todo caso la variable l te indica el nivel donde se encuentra, Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, es lo que buscaba. PD: me encanta esa manera en la que programas, donde simplificas muy buen el código, yo se es hacer siclos y condiciones a la antigua ¿Donde puedo encontrar material nuevo como el que tu aplicas?.

Comment: jajaja!!... no se a que te refieres con eso de "...a la antigua" pero.. tendrá algo que ver con que yo programo hace ya mas de 40 años, en todo caso dificulto que consigas material nuevo, Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: yo hago los ciclos, ejemplos los `for` asi: `for(var i=0;i<x;i++)`, en cambio tu simplificas asi: `for (n in menu)`. ¿Aprendiste `python`? Creo que esa es la sintaxis de ese lenguaje (cuyo cual no he estudiado).

Comment: Si quisiera hacer un `select` con los items del json, con el siguiente formato: `Procesos, Procesos/Lotes, Procesos/Limpieza, Procesos/Mantenimiento, Procesos/Mantenimiento/Planes, Procesos/Mantenimiento/Calendario`. Es lo que se me ocurre para un `select` de clasificaciones. ¿Como haría?

Comment: es lo que he intentado [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krm665zb/)

Comment: te deje un ejemplo de como crear una lista de opciones, Saludos.

Comment: con `optgroup` de html5 no se puede hacer, ¿cierto?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57904/discussion-between-fwbasic-and-pablo-contreras).

Comment: Amigo [acá una duda que tengo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58698/room-for-pablo-contreras-and-fwbasic) acerca de esta pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que tu código era parte que yo publiqué el año pasado, aquí esta lo que te hace falta, espero te sea de utilidad.  Saludos.

```js
var todoMenus;
var menus;
var menuNiveles;
$(document).ready(function(){
  todoMenus = menujson.menu;
  var menuGenerado = GenerarMenus(0, false);
  $("#main-nav").append(menuGenerado);
    //Si quieres pasar estos datos a un nuevo array:
  menuNiveles=[];  
  $.each($("li"),function(i,v){
    $(this).attr('data-idMenu', i+1);
    var nivel = $(this).parents('ul').length;
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).attr("data-nivel",nivel);    
    var padre = $(this).parents('li').attr('data-idMenu');
    padre = padre == undefined ? 0 : padre;
    $(this).attr("title","Nivel:" + nivel);
    var texto = $(this).find("a:first").text();
    var link = $(this).find("a:first").attr('href');    
    var menuNivel = {
      "id": i+1,
      "idPadre": padre,
      "link": link,
      "menu": texto,
      "nivel": nivel
    };    
    //JSON rearmado... con los niveles
    menuNiveles.push(menuNivel);
  });  
  console.log(menuNiveles);  
});

function ObtenerMenus(codigoMenu) {
    menus = [];
    $.each(todoMenus, function (i, v) {
        if (v.id_padre == codigoMenu) {
            menus.push(v);
        }
    });
}
function GenerarMenus(codigoMenu, esSub) {
    var menuGenrado = '';
    if (esSub) {
        menuGenrado = '<ul class="nav nav-stacked">';
    }
    else {
        menuGenrado = '<ul class="nav nav-stacked">';
    }
    ObtenerMenus(codigoMenu);

    if (menus != undefined) {
        $.each(menus, function (i, v) {            
                var subMenu = GenerarMenus(v.id, true);
                if (subMenu.length == 0) {
                    menuGenrado += '<li class=""><a href="' + v.link + '"><i class="' + v.icono + '"></i><span>' + v.titulo + '</span></a>';
                } else {
                    menuGenrado += '<li class=""><a href="' + v.link + '" class="dropdown-collapse"><i class="' + v.icono + '"></i><span>' + v.titulo + '</span><i class="icon-angle-down angle-down"></i></a>';
                    menuGenrado += subMenu;
                }
                menuGenrado += '</li>';            
        });
    }
    menuGenrado += '</ul>'
    if (menuGenrado == '<ul class="nav nav-stacked"></ul>' || menuGenrado == '<ul class="nav nav-stacked"></ul>') {
        menuGenrado = '';
    }
    return menuGenrado;
}

var menujson = {
  "menu": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-dashboard fa-fw",
    "link": "/",
    "titulo": "Tablero"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-tasks fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Procesos"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "id_padre": 2,
    "icono": "fa fa-list-ol fa-fw",
    "link": "/lotes",
    "titulo": "Lotes"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "id_padre": 2,
    "icono": "fa fa-eraser fa-fw",
    "link": "/limpieza",
    "titulo": "Limpieza"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "id_padre": 2,
    "icono": "fa fa-stop fa-fw",
    "link": "/paradasopera",
    "titulo": "Paradas"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "id_padre": 2,
    "icono": "fa fa-wrench fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Mantenimiento"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "id_padre": 6,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/planes",
    "titulo": "Planes"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "id_padre": 6,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/calendario",
    "titulo": "Calendario"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-file-text-o fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Reportes"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "id_padre": 9,
    "icono": "fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw",
    "link": "/estadisticos",
    "titulo": "Estadisticos"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "id_padre": 9,
    "icono": "fa fa-building-o fa-fw",
    "link": "/estaticos",
    "titulo": "Estaticos"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "id_padre": 9,
    "icono": "fa fa-file fa-fw",
    "link": "/parametrizados",
    "titulo": "Parametrizados"
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-wrench fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Opciones"
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-industry fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Marcas de Equipos"
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "id_padre": 22,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/marcas",
    "titulo": "Marcas"
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "id_padre": 22,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/modelos",
    "titulo": "Modelos"
  },
  {
    "id": 32,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-clock-o fa-fw",
    "link": "/turnos",
    "titulo": "Turnos"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-flask fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Productos de Elaboración"
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "id_padre": 14,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/productos",
    "titulo": "Productos"
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "id_padre": 14,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/unidadesdemedicion",
    "titulo": "Unidades de Medición"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-arrows-alt fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Areas y Procesos de Producción"
  },
  {
    "id": 30,
    "id_padre": 15,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/areas",
    "titulo": "Areas"
  },
  {
    "id": 31,
    "id_padre": 15,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/procesos",
    "titulo": "Procesos "
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-steam fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Registro de Equipos"
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "id_padre": 16,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/equipos",
    "titulo": "Equipos"
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "id_padre": 16,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/partes",
    "titulo": "Partes"
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "id_padre": 16,
    "icono": "fa",
    "link": "/subpartes",
    "titulo": "Subpartes"
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "id_padre": 13,
    "icono": "fa fa-user fa-fw",
    "link": "/personas",
    "titulo": "Personas"
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "id_padre": 0,
    "icono": "fa fa-gears fa-fw",
    "link": "#",
    "titulo": "Configuración"
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "id_padre": 18,
    "icono": "fa fa-users fa-fw",
    "link": "/usuarios",
    "titulo": "Usuarios"
  },
  {
    "id": 20,
    "id_padre": 18,
    "icono": "fa fa-suitcase fa-fw",
    "link": "/perfiles",
    "titulo": "Perfiles"
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "id_padre": 18,
    "icono": "fa fa-database fa-fw",
    "link": "/respaldo",
    "titulo": "Respaldo"
  }
  ]
};
/*
* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* main navigation toggling
* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var body, click_event, content, nav, nav_toggler;
    nav_toggler = $("header .toggle-nav");
    nav = $("#main-nav");
    content = $("#content");
    body = $("body");
    click_event = (jQuery.support.touch ? "tap" : "click");
    $("#main-nav .dropdown-collapse").on(click_event, function(e) {
      var link, list;
      e.preventDefault();
      link = $(this);
      list = link.parent().find("> ul");
      if (list.is(":visible")) {
        if (body.hasClass("main-nav-closed") && link.parents("li").length === 1) {
          false;
        } else {
          link.removeClass("in");
          list.slideUp(300, function() {
            return $(this).removeClass("in");
          });
        }
      } else {
        if (list.parents("ul.nav.nav-stacked").length === 1) {
          $(document).trigger("nav-open");
        }
        link.addClass("in");
        list.slideDown(300, function() {
          return $(this).addClass("in");
        });
      }
      return false;
    });
    if (jQuery.support.touch) {
      nav.on("swiperight", function(e) {
        return $(document).trigger("nav-open");
      });
      nav.on("swipeleft", function(e) {
        return $(document).trigger("nav-close");
      });
    }
    nav_toggler.on(click_event, function() {
      if (nav_open()) {
        $(document).trigger("nav-close");
      } else {
        $(document).trigger("nav-open");
      }
      return false;
    });
    $(document).bind("nav-close", function(event, params) {
      var nav_open;
      body.removeClass("main-nav-opened").addClass("main-nav-closed");
      return nav_open = false;
    });
    return $(document).bind("nav-open", function(event, params) {
      var nav_open;
      body.addClass("main-nav-opened").removeClass("main-nav-closed");
      return nav_open = true;
    });
  });

  this.nav_open = function() {
    return $("body").hasClass("main-nav-opened") || $("#main-nav").width() > 50;
  };

  /*
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * plugin initializations
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var touch;
    setTimeAgo();
    setScrollable();
    setSortable($(".sortable"));
    setSelect2();
    setAutoSize();
    setCharCounter();
    setMaxLength();
    setValidateForm();
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * removes .box after click on .box-remove button
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    $(".box .box-remove").on("click", function(e) {
      $(this).parents(".box").first().remove();
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * collapse .box after click on .box-collapse button
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    $(".box .box-collapse").on("click", function(e) {
      var box;
      box = $(this).parents(".box").first();
      box.toggleClass("box-collapsed");
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * password strength
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    if (jQuery().pwstrength) {
      $('.pwstrength').pwstrength({
        showVerdicts: false
      });
    }
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * check all checkboxes in table with class only-checkbox
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    $(".check-all").on("click", function(e) {
      return $(this).parents("table:eq(0)").find(".only-checkbox :checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
    });
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * setting up responsive tabs
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    if (jQuery().tabdrop) {
      $('.nav-responsive.nav-pills, .nav-responsive.nav-tabs').tabdrop();
    }
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * setting up datatables
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    setDataTable($(".data-table"));
    setDataTable($(".data-table-column-filter"));
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * setting up basic wysiwyg
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    if (jQuery().wysihtml5) {
      $('.wysihtml5').wysihtml5();
    }
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * setting up sortable list
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    if (jQuery().nestable) {
      $('.dd-nestable').nestable();
    }
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * affixing main navigation
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    if (!$("body").hasClass("fixed-header")) {
      if (jQuery().affix) {
        $('#main-nav.main-nav-fixed').affix({
          offset: 40
        });
      }
    }
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * setting up bootstrap popovers
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    touch = false;
    if (window.Modernizr) {
      touch = Modernizr.touch;
    }
    if (!touch) {
      $("body").on("mouseenter", ".has-popover", function() {
        var el;
        el = $(this);
        if (el.data("popover") === undefined) {
          el.popover({
            placement: el.data("placement") || "top",
            container: "body"
          });
        }
        return el.popover("show");
      });
      $("body").on("mouseleave", ".has-popover", function() {
        return $(this).popover("hide");
      });
    }
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * setting up bootstrap tooltips
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    touch = false;
    if (window.Modernizr) {
      touch = Modernizr.touch;
    }
    if (!touch) {
      $("body").on("mouseenter", ".has-tooltip", function() {
        var el;
        el = $(this);
        if (el.data("tooltip") === undefined) {
          el.tooltip({
            placement: el.data("placement") || "top",
            container: "body"
          });
        }
        return el.tooltip("show");
      });
      $("body").on("mouseleave", ".has-tooltip", function() {
        return $(this).tooltip("hide");
      });
    }
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * replacing svg images for png fallback
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    if (window.Modernizr && Modernizr.svg === false) {
      $("img[src*=\"svg\"]").attr("src", function() {
        return $(this).attr("src").replace(".svg", ".png");
      });
    }
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * color pickers
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    if (jQuery().colorpicker) {
      $(".colorpicker-hex").colorpicker({
        format: "hex"
      });
      $(".colorpicker-rgb").colorpicker({
        format: "rgb"
      });
    }
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * datetimepickers
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    if (jQuery().datetimepicker) {
      $(".datetimepicker-input").datetimepicker({
        icons: {
          time: "icon-time",
          date: "icon-calendar",
          up: "icon-arrow-up",
          down: "icon-arrow-down"
        }
      });
      $(".datepicker-input").datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,
        icons: {
          time: "icon-time",
          date: "icon-calendar",
          up: "icon-arrow-up",
          down: "icon-arrow-down"
        }
      });
      $(".timepicker-input").datetimepicker({
        pickDate: false,
        icons: {
          time: "icon-time",
          date: "icon-calendar",
          up: "icon-arrow-up",
          down: "icon-arrow-down"
        }
      });
    }
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * setting bootstrap file input
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    if (jQuery().bootstrapFileInput) {
      $('input[type=file]').bootstrapFileInput();
    }
    /*
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * modernizr fallbacks
    * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    if (window.Modernizr) {
      if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
        $("[placeholder]").focus(function() {
          var input;
          input = $(this);
          if (input.val() === input.attr("placeholder")) {
            input.val("");
            return input.removeClass("placeholder");
          }
        }).blur(function() {
          var input;
          input = $(this);
          if (input.val() === "" || input.val() === input.attr("placeholder")) {
            input.addClass("placeholder");
            return input.val(input.attr("placeholder"));
          }
        }).blur();
        return $("[placeholder]").parents("form").submit(function() {
          return $(this).find("[placeholder]").each(function() {
            var input;
            input = $(this);
            if (input.val() === input.attr("placeholder")) {
              return input.val("");
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });

  /*
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * max length counter
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

  this.setMaxLength = function(selector) {
    if (selector == null) {
      selector = $(".char-max-length");
    }
    if (jQuery().maxlength) {
      return selector.maxlength();
    }
  };

  /*
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * character counter
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

  this.setCharCounter = function(selector) {
    if (selector == null) {
      selector = $(".char-counter");
    }
    if (jQuery().charCount) {
      return selector.charCount({
        allowed: selector.data("char-allowed"),
        warning: selector.data("char-warning"),
        cssWarning: "text-warning",
        cssExceeded: "text-error"
      });
    }
  };

  /*
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * autosize feature for expanding textarea elements
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

  this.setAutoSize = function(selector) {
    if (selector == null) {
      selector = $(".autosize");
    }
    if (jQuery().autosize) {
      return selector.autosize();
    }
  };

  /*
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * timeago feature converts static time to dynamically refreshed
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

  this.setTimeAgo = function(selector) {
    if (selector == null) {
      selector = $(".timeago");
    }
    if (jQuery().timeago) {
      jQuery.timeago.settings.allowFuture = true;
      jQuery.timeago.settings.refreshMillis = 60000;
      selector.timeago();
      return selector.addClass("in");
    }
  };

  /*
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * scrollable boxes
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

  this.setScrollable = function(selector) {
    if (selector == null) {
      selector = $(".scrollable");
    }
    if (jQuery().slimScroll) {
      return selector.each(function(i, elem) {
        return $(elem).slimScroll({
          height: $(elem).data("scrollable-height"),
          start: $(elem).data("scrollable-start") || "top"
        });
      });
    }
  };

  /*
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * jquery ui sortable
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

  this.setSortable = function(selector) {
    if (selector == null) {
      selector = null;
    }
    if (jQuery().sortable) {
      if (selector) {
        return selector.sortable({
          axis: selector.data("sortable-axis"),
          connectWith: selector.data("sortable-connect")
        });
      }
    }
  };

  /*
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * select 2 selects
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

  this.setSelect2 = function(selector) {
    if (selector == null) {
      selector = $(".select2");
    }
    if (jQuery().select2) {
      return selector.each(function(i, elem) {
        return $(elem).select2();
      });
    }
  };

  /*
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * datatables
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

  this.setDataTable = function(selector) {
    if (jQuery().dataTable) {
      return selector.each(function(i, elem) {
        var dt, sdom;
        if ($(elem).data("pagination-top-bottom") === true) {
          sdom = "<'row datatables-top'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6 text-right'pf>r>t<'row datatables-bottom'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6 text-right'p>>";
        } else if ($(elem).data("pagination-top") === true) {
          sdom = "<'row datatables-top'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6 text-right'pf>r>t<'row datatables-bottom'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6 text-right'>>";
        } else {
          sdom = "<'row datatables-top'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6 text-right'f>r>t<'row datatables-bottom'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6 text-right'p>>";
        }
        dt = $(elem).dataTable({
          sDom: sdom,
          sPaginationType: "bootstrap",
          "iDisplayLength": $(elem).data("pagination-records") || 10,
          oLanguage: {
            sLengthMenu: "_MENU_ registros por página"
          },
          fnDrawCallback: function(oSettings) {
            $(this).closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_filter] input').css("width", "200px");
            return $(this).closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_filter] input').addClass("form-control input-sm").attr('placeholder', $(this).closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_filter] label').text().replace(":", "..."));
          }
        });
        if ($(elem).hasClass("data-table-column-filter")) {
          return dt.columnFilter();
        }
      });
    }
  };

  /*
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * form validation
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

  this.setValidateForm = function(selector) {
    if (selector == null) {
      selector = $(".validate-form");
    }
    if (jQuery().validate) {
      return selector.each(function(i, elem) {
        return $(elem).validate({
          errorElement: "span",
          errorClass: "help-block has-error",
          errorPlacement: function(e, t) {
            return t.parents(".controls").first().append(e);
          },
          highlight: function(e) {
            return $(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-error has-success").addClass('has-error');
          },
          success: function(e) {
            return e.closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
}).call(this);
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head><title>titulo</title></head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="main-nav"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Actualización**
El ejemplo de como funciona.  Es cuestión de agregar el css para darle formato.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: de hecho fue una respuesta tuya de cual obtuve el código, hay alguna manera de saber en que subniveles se encuentra la función? es decir, ¿por cual subnivel esta pasando?

Comment: Ok ya te entendí.... si...  lo que necesitas hacer.... es cuestión de rearmar el json.... o con los <ul>,<li> ya armados se podrían obtener....

Comment: ¿`rearmar el json`?

Comment: me refiero a generar otro `json` en base al los `li`, que es lo que necesitas hacer con los niveles? dependiendo de eso es la solución, si quieres que el objeto json tenga los niveles, o si quiere que los elemento del menu contengan el nivel..

Comment: Ok, gracias, es lo que necesitaba :D

Comment: Me fuese gustado hacerlo desde la primera función, pero esto me da una solución temporal.